# Android Studio emulator System UI keeps crashing every 10 or so hours of use

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 to run an emulator for developing a react-native app. For some reason the emulator starts freezing and misbehaving after around 10 hours of work. It keeps displaying a message about the System UI not responding and gives me an option to wait or to close the program. Whatever I do it keeps appearing.

I usually fix it by wiping the emulators data from the AVD manager in Android Studio, but it's a big waste of time since I have to reinstall expo and start the whole phone from 0.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### **Try these.**

- Restart android studio and computer.
- In android studio go to files invalidate cache and restart.
- Create another AVD.

otherwise you need to use physical device.